# Generic Matlab code optimization

Tags: matlab, optimization

We know that matlab for loops are very expensive as far as the time is concerned. I am hearing from colleagues saying try to replace for loops with matrix operations. In other words try to replace time consumption with memory consumption.

In a previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19588565/sub-matrix-computations) I have asked how it was possible to use CUDA to compare element by element two matrices. @Eric then suggested my to transform the two `for loops` I had with matrix operations and finally do these matrix operations on the gpu. It was very intuitive. Inspired by this answer I start thinking more seriously matlab code optimizations.

The reason I am doing this post is because I would like to ask if anyone can give some similar intuitive examples or explain efficient coding techniques for writting efficient matlab code? References to any tutorial or a book it would be great.

Thank you!!

Comment: "try and replace time consumption with memory consumption"???? What kind of nonsense statement is that?

Comment: Sorry you are right. I was thinking a case where we could replace some for loops with matrix operations and more specifically matrix multiplications where a new big array can occur which needs a lot of memory.

Comment: @talonmies No nonsense at all. As is well known, there's often a tradeoff between using up more memory and more running time http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space%E2%80%93time_tradeoff

Comment: If you construct 2 MATLAB arrays, and then do `C=A.*B` you are using a matrix operation, one that won't consume any more memory than if you initialized an 'empty' `C` and filled it with a loop.  `A.*B.*c` could end up using more memory as it constructs intermediate matricies, but usually you let MATLAB take care of those issues.

Comment: @LuisMendo, maybe so, but I don't see how this applies. There's no difference in memory consumption when multiplying `A*A` versus `A(i)*A(i)` inside a loop.

Comment: Try to search "`vectorization`" on this site, you'll get some examples.

Comment: @jerad What is this based on? When I try it the matrix multiplication actually consumes twice as much memory, but less time, probably due to greater parallelization.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin, It just seemed like the memory consumption would be equal. However, I'm on a Mac and it's not easily tested. How about when multiplying different matrices `A*B` vs `A(i)*B(i)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Vectorize loops

In Matlab, you can gain speedup by using *Vectorize loops*. MATLAB is speciﬁcally designed to operate on vectors and matrices, so it is usually quicker to perform operations on vectors, or matrices, rather than using a loop. For example:

```
index=0;
for time=0:0.001:60;
    index=index+1;
    waveForm(index)=cos(time);
end;
```

would run considerably faster if replaced with:

```
time=0:0.001:60;
waveForm=cos(time);
```

Functions that you might ﬁnd useful when using vector operations in place of loops include:

- **`any()`** – returns `true` if any element is non-zero.
- **`size()`** – returns a vector containing the number of elements in an array along each dimension.
- **`find()`** – returns the indices of any non-zero elements. To get the non-zero values themselves you can use something like `a(find(a));`.
- **`cumsum()`** – returns a vector containing the cumulative sum of the elements in its argument vector, e.g. `cumsum([0:5])` returns `[0 1 3 6 10 15]`.
- **`sum()`** – returns the sum of all the elements in a vector, e.g. `sum([0:5])` returns `15`.

---

Besides replacing `for`-loops with matrix operations, you can maximizing code performance by optimizing memory access:

### 1. Preallocate arrays before accessing them within loops

When creating or repeatedly modifying arrays within loops, always allocate the arrays beforehand. Of all three techniques, this familiar one can give the biggest performance improvement.

[image]

Code segment 2 executes in 99.8% less time (580 times faster) than segment 1 on machine A, and in 99.7% less time (475 times faster) than segment 1 on machine B.

### 2. Store and access data in columns

When processing 2-D or N-D arrays, access your data in columns and store it so that it is easily accessible by columns.

[image]

Code segment 2 executes in 33% less time than segment 1 on machine A, and in 55% less time than segment 1 on machine B.

### 3. Avoid creating unnecessary variables

When creating new variables or variables that are functions of existing data sets, ensure that they are essential to your algorithm, particularly if your data set is large.

[image]

Code segment 2 executes in 40% less time than code segment 1 on machine A and in 96% less time on machine B.

[image]

Code segment 4 executes in 40% less time than code segment 3 on machine A and in 59% less time on machine B.

---

**References:**

- [Proﬁling, Optimization, and Acceleration of MATLAB code](http://www.sal.ufl.edu/NewComers/matlab_optimization.pdf)
- [Programming Patterns: Maximizing Code Performance by Optimizing Memory Access](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/programming-patterns-maximizing-code-performance-by-optimizing-memory-access.html)
- [Writing Fast MATLAB Code](http://www.ee.columbia.edu/~marios/matlab/Writing_Fast_MATLAB_Code.pdf)
- [Introduction to Computers for Engineers](http://www.blaseur.com/l10.pdf)

Comment: What exactly is the point of example 2? Is it that 'switching' rows is more efficient than switching columns and thus that a `1000*N` by `N` matrix is usually preferred over a `N` by `1000*N` one?

Comment: Yes. The reason is that, in Matlab, matrix are stored in a col-major way.